# What are the current best explanations as to why does division of labor work?

Tags: complexity

What are the current best explanations as to why does division of labor work?

It seems like black magic in complex economies.

Comment: Because different people are better or worse in different activities? And also different types of work require different skills and knowledge all of which cannot be acquired in considerable amount of time (even human lifetime).

Comment: @rus9384 But there's also some decision made between e.g. passion vs responsibility as well. One can also "falsify" the motives. One can choose to do less useful job instead of a more useful one. Due to opportunity cost one loses the chance to do other things, if one chooses one.

Comment: It is impossible for a single person to be great in everything. That's why division of labor exists. Job usefulness is vague. The one who pays much has a reason to do it, because it is useful for the employer. Consider actors, some actors are paid well, but one can argue they do not do anything useful, compared to doctors, for example. But they attract audience which will pay for tickets in cinemas.

Comment: Even assuming that this is a question about philosophy rather than economics it is a kind of question more suitable for reading about in encyclopedias rather than asking on SE, e.g. [Wikipedia's Division of Labor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_of_labour).

Comment: It's very simply about getting efficiency from bulk purchasing and reduced context switching. And it doesn't always work

Comment: @Richard:  It's also about return on investment.  It would take at least five years minimum to become as good as I am at developing software.  If I take that five years out of a forty-five year career, we're getting forty years of first-rate development from a five-year investment.  If I have another job I have to be that good at, I'm spending ten years honing my crafts and thirty-five years of top performance.  The return on investment of having me develop software and someone else design fashions is higher than of having each of us do both jobs.

Comment: Yes.. but a developer is also a sys-admin, project manager, teacher and patient teacher. Software engineering might seem like division of labour but it isn't and in fact this is why I say it doesn't always work. Rolls Royce hand build cars and have craftsmen that do more on each vehicle than stamp out steering wheels because their product is about quality. What would happen to the overall system for which you write software if you didn't know how it all hangs together and get involved?

Comment: That having been said.. there is a trend now to split enterprise software into tiers with different skill sets.   But that's probably why we can't deliver large projects anymore and the world is going to hell in a Nissan GTR.

Answer (score 0):

**Complex economies - or technologically advanced economies ?**

The division of labour, for the reasons Smith identifies below, would seem *more* relevant the more complex an economy is. But perhaps you have in mind that advanced economies now standardly use technology which is simple enough for anyone to operate without the specialisation involved in the division of labour. If this isn't your point, I think I need you to say in more detail what the tension between the division of labour and the complexity of the economy is.

**Adam Smith - and a gap in Smith**

*Adam Smith*

> In the opening paragraph of his Wealth of Nations, Adam Smith [1776, Book 1,
>    Chapter 1] postulated that the "greatest improvement in the productive powers of
>    labour, and the greater part of the skill, dexterity, and judgment ... seem to have
>    been the effects of the division of labour." According to Smith, the benefit of the
>    division of labor has three main sources. **First**, the division of labor increases the
>    dexterity of each worker as he specializes in a single operation. **Second**, it saves time
>    that is otherwise lost in changing from one task to another; and **last**, it facilitates the
>    use of machines that complement specialized labor. (Wenli Chen, ' A Benefit from the Division of Labor that Adam
>    Smith Missed', Eastern Economic Journal, Vol. 38, No. 3 (Summer 2012), pp. 310-318 : 310.)

*Smith's gap*

> There is in fact another important source of benefit from the division of labor that
>    Smith failed to mention, namely that the division of labor shortens the time required
>    in the capital formation process and makes continuous roundabout production
>    (that is, production with capital-using technology) possible. To illustrate, imagine
>    a fishing village where the villagers can use two different fishing "technologies": one
>    is to fish with their bare hands; the alternative is to make nets first and then catch
>    more fish with nets. Assume for simplicity that it takes one day to make a net. In the
>    absence of the division of labor, each villager catches fish with his bare hands on
>    Day 1 and consumes some of the catch. On Day 2 he makes a net, which will be
>    available for use on Day 3. With the division of labor, the production arrangement
>    is different. Some villagers fish with their bare hands on Day 1, others make nets.
>    As a result, nets are available for use from Day 2, one day earlier than the case with
>    no division of labor. This simple example points to an additional mechanism
>    through which the division of labor improves individual welfare. That is, the
>    division of labor shortens capital formation time — the capital good, net, becomes
>    available one day earlier and consequently the villagers enjoy the benefit of the more
>    productive "capital-using technology" sooner. In addition, the division of labor
>    enables continuous production with capital-using technology — a villager does not
>    have to stop fishing to make a new net when his old net wears out. (Chen : 310.)

*The shadow of Marx*

Marx had an uneasy relationship to the division of labour. His views changed over time but one aspect of the division of labour that he did not think had any benefit is capitalism's 'confining of managerial, administrative, and intellectual work to some people and of manual work to others'. Among other things, this blocked the 'the all-round development of the workers' (J. Plamenatz, Karl Marx's Philosophy of Man, Oxford : OUP, 1975 : 169). This is only a glimpse at Marx's complex and shifting attitude but it is worth noting as a counterweight to the near-universal celebration of the division of labour.